# Conexão com o Banco cai após determinado tempo

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, rest, tomcat

Tenho um servidor onde tenho várias aplicações web conectadas ao banco de dados(`Mysql`). O problema é que se algum sistema ficar ocioso ele perde a conexão com o banco e eu tenho que dar um refresh na aplicação pra que tudo volte ao normal.

Eu estava contornando esse problema com uma `Thread` que fazia um ping no banco de dados a cada 1 hora. Porém agora que estou trabalhando com `WEBServices` esse método não está mais funcionando.

Li em alguns lugares que o `Mysql` derruba todas as conexões caso fique ocioso por 8 horas. E também achei várias possíveis soluções, como configurar o `C3P0`, etc. Mas mesmo fazendo essas configurações o erro ainda persiste. No Log do `Tomcat` tenho esses erros:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: commit failed
Caused by: org.hibernate.TransactionException: unable to commit against JDBC connection
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLNonTransientConnectionException: No operations allowed after connection closed.
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Software caused connection abort: socket write error
```

Estou usando `Hibernate`, e minhas configurações estão dessa forma:

```
<!-- Database connection settings -->
        <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
        <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bd</property>
        <property name="connection.username">root</property>
        <property name="connection.password"></property>
        <property name="connection.autoReconnect">true</property>
        <property name="connection.autoReconnectForPools">true</property>

        <!-- C3P0 -->
        <property name="c3p0.acquire_increment">5</property>
        <property name="c3p0.timeout">0</property>
        <property name="c3p0.min_size">3</property>
        <property name="c3p0.max_size">100</property>
        <property name="c3p0.max_statements">0</property>
        <property name="c3p0.idle_test_period">3000</property>
```

Coloquei até o `timeout` como 0 pois em alguns lugares falam que dessa forma a conexão nunca expira, porém continua expirando.

Está configuração minha está certa? É necessário fazer alguma outra configuração? Existe outra maneira de resolver esse problema?

---

**Atualizado**

Percebi que mesmo com esses erros ainda consigo incluir, alterar e editar os dados porém sempre que tento realizar uma dessas operações tenho como retorno **erro 500** e a tela fica congelada, ou seja os campos não são limpos.

---

**Atualizado 23-12-2015**

Exemplo de um método onde fexo a conexão:

```
public void salvar(Agenda agenda) {
        Session sessao = HibernateUtil.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        Transaction transacao = null;
        try {
            transacao = sessao.beginTransaction();
            sessao.save(agenda);
            transacao.commit();
        } catch (RuntimeException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
            throw ex;

        } finally {
            sessao.close();
        }
    }
```

Todos os métodos do `DAO` tem o `finally` com o `sessao.close()`.

Estava pensando, tenho essa propriedade no `hibernate.cfg`:

```
<!-- Enable Hibernate's automatic session context management -->
<property name="current_session_context_class">thread</property>
```

Será que isso poderia interferir nas propriedades do `C3P0` que coloquei?

Comment: Eu tentei isso porém não reiniciei o serviço do `Mysql` vou tentar novamente, no caso eu passo esse valor de 180 mesmo?

Comment: Esse link explica de forma detalhada como resolver este problema. http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,139821,160175

Comment: @Techies http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3511422/java-c3p0-how-can-i-configure-autoreconnect-true  Esquece aquele comentário meu, desculpe mas não vai resolver eu problema. Este link é de um problema igual ao seu. E é ensinado como resolver isso.

Comment: Vou fazer o teste. Obrigado. Agora tenho que espera o sistema ficar ocioso kk

Comment: Fiz os testes porém a conexão entre a API e o banco continuam caindo, e o mais estranho é que as consultas e e as operações de excluir, salvar editar são feitas porém da erro 500. De inicio nem parece que foi salvo

Comment: Ao que parece algumas das tuas rotinas pode estar fechando a conexão. Coloque também como está fazendo acesso ao banco

Comment: Veja esse exemplo http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-firstapp-helpers

Comment: Vou testar e ver se funciona

Comment: Eu já tinha o HibernateUtil implementado, fiz mais alguns testes e não funcionou

Comment: Acho que a chave pra entender seu problema está na maneira como você abre a conexão na sua aplicação. Você inicia e termina quando uma conexão? Está sempre aberta? Se sim, porque? Dá pra postar trechos de código onde você abre e fecha a conexão?

Comment: Atualizei a pergunta

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Há varias coisas para tentar testar, vou colocar algumas.

Na linha de conexão pode tentar colocar o argumento de autoReconnect

```
<property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/bd?autoReconnect=true</property>
```

Adicione também um provider para o [C3P0](https://memoirsofhereafter.files.wordpress.com/2015/08/c3p0.png)

```
<property name="connection.provider_class">org.hibernate.connection.C3P0ConnectionProvider</property>
```

> E por fim, a propriedade para testar a conexão em um checkout.

Crie um arquivo [c3p0.properties](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#c3p0_properties), ou caso já estiver usando o arquivo [c3p0-config.xml](http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#c3p0-config.xml) adicione a propriedade como `true`
http://www.mchange.com/projects/c3p0/index.html#testConnectionOnCheckout

> ***Uma segunda alternativa***

É encontrar o arquivo `my.ini` ou `my.cnf` no diretório do `mysql` respectivo a seu *sistema operacional*, nesse [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/option-files.html) há exemplos de caminhos onde se encontra o diretório.

Caso não encontrar inicialmente, verifique também se o arquivo não se encontra ***oculto***. Em qualquer um dos dois funciona.

Ao encontrar, adicione as seguintes linhas com os valores, que são reconhecidos em *segundos*

```
wait_timeout = 99999999999999999999999 
interactive_timeout = 99999999999999999999999
```

Por padrão esses valores mesmo que implicitos são de `8 horas`, ou `28800 segundos`.

Comment: eu tenho que criar esse c3p0.properties ou posso fazer a config no arquivo do hibernate mesmo?

Comment: Quando coloco um `provider` tenho esse erro: `Caused by: org.hibernate.service.spi.ServiceException: Unable to create requested service [org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.spi.ConnectionProvider]`

Comment: Pode testar, mas o padrão da linha é diferente das setadas por você. Talvez seja porque não esta utilizando o c3p0 do hibernate, mas a outra versão disponivel? http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-c3p0 http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.mchange/c3p0 Mas é provavel que as duas sejam necessárias, porém a mudança fica na configuração.

Comment: Realmente eu não tinha a dependência do hibernate-c3p0, achei que já era integrado. vou testar novamente o provider

Comment: O `provider` continua sem funcionar. O restante que você passou está funcionando

Comment: Mas você consegue provocar o problema que esta tendo, para testar as configurações?

Comment: Então eu sempre tive que esperar até o dia seguinte, pois o sistema está no servidor e o erro só acontece quando fica inativo por algumas horas.

Comment: E contou quantas horas, é sempre a mesma quantidade?

Comment: De acordo com o que li são 8 horas, que é o padrão do mysql

Comment: Mas então o problema é na configuração do MySQL e não na sua aplicação, você alterou e aumentou esse tempo de timeout?

Comment: Sim aumentei, no mesmo lugar vi que isso poderia ser resolvido através do pool de conexões do hibernate, pra não deixar perder a conexão com o banco.

Comment: No my.cnf? Talvez se alterar apenas lá, não precisaria adicionar dependencias a mais no projeto apenas para resolver esse problema

Comment: Já fiz essa alteração, de uma olhada no log de inicialização do Hibernate, será que o c3p0 está funcionando:
http://pastebin.com/B7XA1CRw

Comment: Hm, estranho. Você pode mostrar como esta seu my.cnf?

Comment: Posso sim, 1 minuto

Comment: Para o Hibernate C3P0 inicializar, é necessário o provider. Se esta acontecendo o erro, tente mudar para as propriedades do próprio hibernate c3p0.

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/33378/discussion-between-techies-and-douglas-galdino).

Comment: Adicionei essas duas propriedades no arquivo `my.ini ` e funcionou.

Answer (score 1):

Dê uma olhada nas configurações desse outro post, acredito que com isso o seu problema será resolvido.

Atente-se para as propriedades ***idleConnectionTestPeriod*** e ***maxIdleTimeExcessConnections***

[Best configuration of c3p0 [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12507021/best-configuration-of-c3p0)

Comment: Obrigado, irei testar